# Relation and Cartesian Product

Tags: relations

Let $A=\{-1,2,5,8\}$, $B=\{0,1,3,6,7\}$ and $R$ be the relation is one less than form $A$ to $B$. Then,

1) Find $R$ as a set of ordered pairs

2) Find domain and range of $R$.

3) Find $R^{-1}$ as a set of ordered pairs.

4) Find the domain and range of $R^{-1}$.

My Attempt:

First I calculated the Cartesian Product of $A$ and $B$ as

$$A\times B=\{(-1,0),(-1,1),(-1,3),(-1,6),(-1,7),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,6),(2,7),(5,0),(5,1),(5,3),(5,6),(5,7),(8,0),(8,1),(8,3),(8,6),(8,7)\}$$.

Now, I could not understand the condition given for the relation.

Comment: "...$R$ be the relation is one less than form $A$ to $B$..." What do you mean by that? Something like $R=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B\mid a+1=b\}$ maybe?

Comment: @Drhab, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Actually I asked you a question. This because it is not clear to me yet what relation $R$ you are dealing with. For me there is nothing to elaborate at this stage of ignorance.

Comment: @Drhab, I am confused on that, too?

Comment: Well, as I said: I expect it is $R:=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B\mid a\text{ is one less than }b\}$. Can you find the answers for this $R$?

Comment: @Drhab, I can find the anwers with that.

Comment: Nice to hear. Success.